# Proof of exponential inequality

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, exponential-function

**Claim**: For any $c \in \mathbb{R}$ and any constant $\lambda > 0$ we have that $$\frac{e^{-\lambda c} + e^{\lambda c}}{2} \leq e^{(\lambda c)^2/2}$$

The place I observed the inequality proves it by taking the Taylor expansion on both sides of the equation but it seems to me that there should be a simpler way of proving it.

My initial idea was to apply the natural logarithm to both sides:
$$\ln(e^{-\lambda c} + e^{\lambda c}) - \ln(2) \leq \frac{1}{2}\lambda^2c^2$$

However, I got stuck here. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah, my apologies - Edited now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove the inequality $\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2} \leq e^{x^2/2}$ for all real numbers $x$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3082185/prove-the-inequality-fracexe-x2-leq-ex2-2-for-all-real-numbers) . Found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7Be%5Ex%2Be%5E%7B-x%7D%7D%7B2%7D%20%5Cle%20e%5E%7B%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E2%7D%7B2%7D%7D%24&p=1). Note it has several answers which don't use the Taylor expansion and, in particular, this [answer](/a/3082215) completes your initial idea.

Comment: FYI, other questions asking to prove this inequality are [Proving that $\frac{e^x + e^{-x}}2 \le e^{x^2/2}$](/q/654839), [How to prove $ \frac{e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2} \le e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$?](/q/882422), [Why is $\frac{(e^x+e^{-x})}{2}$ less than $e^\frac{x^2}{2}$?](/q/1656988), [show that $\operatorname{ch}(t) \leq e^{\frac{t^2}{2}}$](/q/3141803) and [Proving $\forall x\in\mathbb R : \dfrac{e^x + e^{-x}}2 \le e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}$ with Cauchy's MVT](/q/834040).